# Remote control direction keys repeat twice in MythTV

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv, lirc

I have a gray Hauppauge remote control that I have mostly working with MythTV (Mythbuntu 11.10). The only remaining problem is that if I press the Up, Down, Left, or Right buttons on the remote, the selection in MythTV is moved two places in that direction. I've tried playing around with the `repeat` and `delay` settings in the `lircrc` files but they have no effect. The `irw` command reports these button presses as single presses. Any tips on how to debug this?

I got as much as I have working using the advice on [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1856731).

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Fjni2ygM) are all of my various lirc configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a windows media center remote. X was picking up the
remote as well as mythtv.

If you are having the same problem, you have two choices:

1) Tell X to ignore your remote control.

2) Remove the arrow keys from the lirc mapping for mythtv so that X controls the arrow keys and lirc controls the rest.

Unfortunately, I've forgotten the setting to do (1). Hopefully someone else will be able to guide you further.